# How to Fix "Attempted to call an undefined method named "createNamedBuilder..."?

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony4, formbuilder

I'm trying to create a named form (builder) within my controller like

```
...
$form = $this->createNamedBuilder('form1', $data)
->add(...)
->getForm();
```

But i get the title-mentioned error.
When i check the abstract controller trait class there are no `createNamed()` or `createNamedBuilder()` functions in there.

How do i create a named form with a form builder?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to This](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html#accessing-the-form-factory) you need to acquire the FormFactory(Interface via Dependency Injection).

Adding `FormFactoryInterface $formFactory` to my controller method's parameters and using it like

```
$formFactory->createNamedBuilder('name', FormType::class, $data)...
```

did the trick.